# How to access a SOAP service through an authenticated proxy server in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, proxy

Let me start by saying I am new to C# and SOAP services. I need to wring a program that will read data from a flat file and make a call to a SOAP web service to insert the data into that system.

My network is behind a proxy server that I have to authenticate with a username and password in order to access anything external to our network or on the internet. I can not figure out how to do this.  I have been searching for answers and trying the results I have found, but I have had no luck. The error message I get is

> "The request failed with an empty response"

I have set up the service in SOAPUI, and if I supply my proxy settings to the SOAPUI preferences, it is able to leave our network and get a response.

The username and password I have in the example below are not real, but the response doesn't change either way.  It seems to me like it never attempts to access or authenticate through the proxy server.

Can anyone help me out?  Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleApp6.ASC.Service1 soap = new ConsoleApp6.ASC.Service1();
            ConsoleApp6.ASC.UserCredentialsSoapHeader credential = new ConsoleApp6.ASC.UserCredentialsSoapHeader();           
            credential.UserName = "soap_user_name";
            credential.Password = "soap_password";
            soap.UserCredentialsSoapHeaderValue = credential;

            soap.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://gateway.zscalertwo.net:80/", true);
            soap.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");


            try
            {
                ASC.AppraiserLicense licenceInfo = soap.GetLicenseByLicenseNumber("46000049784", 1, "NY");
                Console.WriteLine(licenceInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXPr3.jpg)

> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with an empty response.
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClie
>   ntMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream,
>   Boolean asyncCal l)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodN ame, Object[] parameters)    at
>   ConsoleApp6.ASC.Service1.GetLicenseByLicenseNumber(String
>   LicenseNumber, B yte LicType, String st_abbr) in
>   C:\Users\mkurick\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Pr
>   ojects\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Web References\ASC\Reference.cs:line
>   120    at ConsoleApp6.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   C:\Users\mkurick\Documents\Visu al Studio
>   2017\Projects\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\Program.cs:line 26

Comment: Please add the relevant console output within the question rather than as an image

Comment: It was just the error message "The request failed with an empty response." but I have added it as you requested.

Comment: Also having this issue - did you ever solve it?